# Unable to create process

Tags: python, django, cmd, prompt

I updated my python version and when I try to run server on prompt for django I get this error.

Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\ALFRED\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
manage.py runserver': The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

[image]This error occurs when the file system of the target device is corrupted or damaged, making your hard drive, USB or external hard drive inaccessible.
Are you sure you typed the right command python manage.py runserver.